# Буквы наезжают друг на друга, текст игнорирует padding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opera, windows-8

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой и не могу найти решение. Данная проблема наблюдается мною из Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m и Opera 30.0.1835.59. ОС: Windows 8.1 64-bit. Это больше похоже на баг браузера, но я не увидел такой проблемы через [browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com), поэтому не исключаю, что дело может быть в моем компьютере.

Когда я открываю в вышеуказанных браузерах данный сайт: http://zinkit.club/, то либо же сразу, либо после 3-4 перезагрузок можно увидеть такие аномалии:

- в блоке текста под слайдером в некоторых словах буквы наезжают друг
  на друга
- в этом же блоке и еще в одном другом текст вылазит за допустимую
  ширину (налазит на padding)
- при нажатии на пункты меню, текст нажатого пункта меню становится в две строчки
  вместо одной

[image: скриншоты ошибки]

Comment: сторонние шрифты используете ?

Comment: да, использую Open Sans. Заметил, что если поставить базовый шрифт, то проблемы нет. Но также интересно, что если отключить слайдер, то проблема также исчезает - а это уже мистика.

Comment: да - мистика. Попробуй Open Sans с гугла грузить, может просто в шрифте проблема.

Answer (score 2):

можно `overflov: hidden;` задать, обычно помогает!

Comment: почитали бы http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow

Comment: обычно, это в каких ситуациях?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?